# Hide column in SP list based on entry from another column in same list

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint

I have one column that depends on a result from another column in SharePoint 2013 list. In my display form, if in column 1 result is Yes, than column2 should be visible. If it is No, column2 should be hidden.

Below is a script that I tried but failed to make it work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  if($("#Column1").text()=="No")
  {
    $("#Column2a").hide();
    $("#Column2b").hide();
  }
  else if($("#Column1").text()=="Yes")
  {
    $("#Column2a").show();
    $("#Column2b").show();
  }
});
</script>
```

In my display form I added IDs to column1 and column2 tds.

```
    <tr>
      <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>Column 1</nobr>
        </H3>
      </td>
      <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody" id="Column1">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Column1"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" id="Column2a">
         <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
         <nobr>Column 2</nobr>
         </H3>
      </td>
      <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody"  id="Column2b">
         <xsl:value-of select="@Column2" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

What should I change in code?

*EDIT:*
To make it more clear, 1st I edited display form and added IDs to tds, then I created script that I put in display form page.

Comment: Can you be more specific in what is not working - "failed to make it work" can cover a wide variety of things

Comment: script and part of code I posted are not working. I don't know how to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trim your content:

```js
if($("#Column1").text().trim() == "No")
{
  $("#Column2a").hide();
  $("#Column2b").hide();
}
else if($("#Column1").text().trim() == "Yes")
{
  $("#Column2a").show();
  $("#Column2b").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
      <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>Column 1</nobr>
        </H3>
      </td>
      <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody" id="Column1">
        No
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" id="Column2a">
         <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
         <nobr>Column 2</nobr>
         </H3>
      </td>
      <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody"  id="Column2b">
         test
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Just as a thought, you may want to hide the row rather than the columns (if you are hiding all columns in the row)